# Bootstrap-3-Typeahead não lista as opções

Tags: javascript, autocompletar

estou usando plugin Bootstrap-3-Typeahead que deveria funcionar de forma simples.

Meu método do lado do servidor ta certinho, trazendo as opções de seleção mas não lista. Pelo que li no git, nem precisa de css extra, mas não lista.

Segue meu código:

```
$("#pesquisa").typeahead({
                source: function (query) {
                    return $.get("/Estabelecimento/GetDados", { q: query });
                },
                minLength: 3
            });
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa"  class="form-control typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Pesquisar" />
                <div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Segue imagem do retorno da minha chamada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não está a inicializar correctamente os dados.

```
 $.get("Estabelecimento/GetDados", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("#pesquisa").typeahead({   
        source: data,
        minLength: 3
      });
    }, 'json');
```

Comment: Da forma que você informou, ele lista os nomes conforme imagem que anexei e a pesquisa funciona por Ameri, Son, etc.. mas minha ideia inicial seria realizar em uma outra coluna de serviço e listar os nomes dos establecimento com base no que o usuário digitar, por exemplo.. se ele digitar Cacau, listar Ameircanas e Carrefou, pois nessas duas na coluna serviços tem essa palava base nase dados. Ou esse plugin só funciona dessa forma que você informou?

Comment: Este é funcionamento básico, penso ser possível realizar o que pede. Por favor marque esta resposta como correcta (por favor recompense o esforço) já que responde ao que pediu e abra uma nova pergunta indicando o que necessita e indicado os dados.  Não coloque os dados sobre a forma de imagem dificulta a cópia para podermos testar.

Comment: Acho que ficou mais claro a dúvida agora -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316058/bootstrap-3-typeahead-listar-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-base-em-pesquisa-exibindo-outro-campo