# Bootstrap-3-Typeahead, listar opções com base em pesquisa exibindo outro campo

Tags: jquery, autocompletar

Usando plugin Bootstrap-3-Typeahead realizando a pesquisa com base no que o usuário digite e exibido a informação de outra coluna da base de dados.

Meu método do lado do servidor realiza o filtro com base na coluna serviços e retorna o nome (colune nome) dos estabelecimentos como resultado e ta certinho, ou seja, quado é informado Site ou Informatica o filtro busca as empresas teste Americanas e Microsoft e outras que tenho como teste, porém não lista como opção de seleção.

Neste outro post: [Bootstrap-3-Typeahead não lista as opções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/315693/bootstrap-3-typeahead-n%C3%A3o-lista-as-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es/315701) o Jorge me mostrou que funciona de forma simples, mas não atende a minha demanda.

Segue meu código:

```
$("#pesquisa").typeahead({
                source: function (query) {
                    return $.get("/Estabelecimento/GetDados", { q: query });
                },
                minLength: 3
            });
```

Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa"  class="form-control typeahead" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Pesquisar" />
                <div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Retorno da minha chamada $.get quando busco por site, ele filtra e trás os nomes abaixo:

```
["Americanas", "Apple", "C & A", "Carrefour", "Microsfot", "Riachuelo", "Saraiva", "Sony"]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Prova de conceito**

Para o exemplo estou a usar uma lista de países disponível num serviço REST para simular um pedido get.

Efetue a pesquisa em inglês, ex. Port -> Portugal, Spa ->Spain, mas também pode colocar a abreviatura com 3 letras ex. PRT, ESP

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

  var data = $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2',null, function(data){

    $("#typeahead").typeahead({
    source: data,
      matcher: function (item){
         
         if(item.alpha3Code.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.query.toUpperCase())>=0) {
           //console.log(item.alpha3Code);
            return true;
          }
          
          else if(item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.query.toUpperCase())>=0) {
           //console.log(item.name);
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            return false
          }
      },
    autoSelect: true
  });


})


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/3.1.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<input type="text" id="typeahead">
```

**Atualização**

Você pode usar a função na mesma

```
source: function (query) {
   return $.get("/Estabelecimento/GetDados", { q: query });
```

em vez de

```
source: data,
```

No exemplo não usei porque estou a usar uma fonte de dados pública e o exemplo deixaria de funcionar.

Assim ao devolver a sua lista já filtrada a função matcher deve devolver sempre *true*, vai substituir a função nativa que verifica que o texto corresponde à chave de pesquisa.

```
matcher: function (item){return true;}),
```

para que todos os elementos da sua lista correspondam.

Assim o plugin vai aceitar como resposta qualquer elemento da sua lista (que já está previamente filtrada).

No caso apresentado se fizesse o filtro no URL o exemplo poderia não funcionar, apenas queria mostrar o funcionamento.

Comment: Ivan pode indicar se respondi à sua pergunta?

Comment: Não... não resolveu.. Veja la na pergunta que eu digo... Com base no que o usuário digitar eu devo buscar na coluna serviço, mas a exibição deve ser o nome dos estabelecimentos. Tipo. tenho 2 estabelecimentos chamados, Americanas e Microsoft e em cada um deles tenho na coluna serviço a palavra site, ao buscar por site, deveria aparecer os 2 estabelecimentos como sugestão. O que não ocorre.. da forma postada eu já havia conseguido..

Comment: Modifiquei para ir ao encontro do que está pedir , pode conjugar com o método anterior mas assim tem a resposta exacta ao pediu

Comment: Ainda não atende a minha necessidade. dessa forma que vc fez agora ao chamar meu método /Estabelecimento/GetDados/?q=, como não passa nada como parametro já trás todos os registro sem executar o filtro que deveria ocorrer do lado do servidor.. Vou adotar outro pluging.. como o autocomplete do jquery.