# Select2 + Jquery - Problema no Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Consegui fazer o PlUGIN Select2 funcionar, porém o autocomplete não funciona.

```
$(function () {

    $("#disciplina").select2({
        placeholder: "Disciplina",
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        ajax:{
            url: "busca.asp",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 150,
            data: function(params){
                return{
                    text: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function(data, params){
                params.page = params.page || 1;     
                return{ 

                    results: data,
                    pagination:{
                        more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });

});
```

[image: Ao começar a digitar a disciplina BIOLOGIA deveria buscar]

Alguém já passou por isso?

O retorno com console.log(data);

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

console.log(params);

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode fazer um dump da informação que está receber do servidor (console.log)

Comment: @JorgeCosta já tentei colocar o console no retorno do ajax, mas a função deixa de funcionar. return{
      console.log(params.term); 
                        text: params.term      
                    };

Comment: cara, to umas 3 semanas nisso de popular um select, tá muito dificil. Cheguei perto agora, mas tô esbarrando nisso.

Comment: Faz console.log(data) antes do return, se estiver a usar o Chrome veja no inspector

Comment: @JorgeCosta fiz no processResults e deu certo, vou postar na pergunta a imagem do retorno.

Comment: Publiquei uma resposta essencialmente é da sua responsabilidade filtrar os dados do lado servidor quando usa ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema**

Os dados não são estão a ser filtrados quando é digitada uma chave de pesquisa.

Segundo a documentação no site do plugin: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

> Select2 expects results from the remote endpoint to be filtered on the
>   server side.

**Tradução**

O Select2 espera que resultados devolvidos pelo *endpoint* remoto  definido sejam filtrados do lado do servidor.

**Exemplo**

Neste exemplo *data* é uma função permite personalizar o url da pesquisa, do lado servidor esses parâmetros devem ser utilizados para filtrar a lista devolvida.

> Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/select2/repos',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        type: 'public'
      }

      // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&type=public
      return query;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas tô desistindo, não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer isso. Cansado já. Valeu pela atenção.

Comment: Por favor coloque a minha resposta como certa, vou lhe indicar outro plugin  a ver em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316058/bootstrap-3-typeahead-listar-opções-com-base-em-pesquisa-exibindo-outro-campo

Comment: Eu vi la, mas não atende o que quero. É um autocomplete somente, o select2 é um select dinâmico.

Comment: creio que eu esteja muito perto da solução.

Comment: Não percebo porque não marcou a resposta como correcta, ela responde correctamente ao seu problema, o plugin que recomendei é efectivamente dinâmico, pode alterar o datasource enquanto altera a chave pesquisa

Comment: Ele não lista todas as opções e não se parece com um select, mas para outras situações é bem útil, mas não me atende.

Comment: o que quero é isso https://www.aprovaconcursos.com.br/questoes-de-concurso/questoes/instituicao/ENEM/filtro/auto